Google Maps JavaScript API: Map turns grey with "Sorry, we have no imagery here" when zooming in
I am experiencing issues with the Google Maps JavaScript API in my Next.js application. When I zoom in on the map, I receive the message "Sorry, we have no imagery here" and the map turns grey. Checking the network tab in the developer tools, I see the error (failed) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB.
Here are the details:

Problem Description:

When the map is zoomed out, everything works fine and the map is displayed correctly.
When I zoom in, the map turns grey and shows the message "Sorry, we have no imagery here".
The network tab shows the error: (failed) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB.


Environment Details:

Next.js application
.env.local file:
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=your_actual_api_key_here


loader.js:
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  version: 'weekly',
  libraries: ['places'], // Add any necessary libraries
});

export default loader;


MapComponent.jsx:
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import loader from '../path/to/loader'; // Adjust path as needed

const MapComponent = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    loader.load().then(() => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        new google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
          zoom: 8,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" ref={mapRef} style={{ height: '500px', width: '100%' }} />;
};

export default MapComponent;


next.config.js:
const withSvgr = (nextConfig = {}) => ({
  ...nextConfig,
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,

      use: [
        options.defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        },
      ],
    });

    if (typeof nextConfig.webpack === 'function') {
      return nextConfig.webpack(config, options);
    }

    return config;
  },
});

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  env: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  },
};

module.exports = withSvgr(nextConfig);




Additional Information:

The issue occurs only when zooming in. When the map is zoomed out, it displays correctly.
The network tab shows 404 errors for certain map tiles with the status "NOT_FOUND".



Has anyone else encountered this issue? What might be causing the map to fail when zoomed in, and how can I resolve it?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I Have Tried:

Verified that my API key is correct and active.
Checked that the necessary APIs (e.g., Maps JavaScript API) are enabled in the Google Cloud Console.
Ensured that there are no restrictions (HTTP referrer or IP address) on the API key that would prevent its usage.
Implemented CORS settings on my server to allow requests from all origins.
Attempted to load the map in multiple browsers with the same result.


Is this happening using plain javscript? If so, could you please provide a sample app?
